# AngularJS: How to inject or require third parties library in directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, lazy-loading

What I am trying to do is my own angular directive. In this angular directive I would need a third party library.

Just to put an example I want to create a directive for tag clouds with d3.

In that case I have d3 accessible via d3 and then I would need to require the library d3.layout.cloud.js

I don't want to put my app plenty of scripts in the index so my questions is how to achieve that? 
I mean, what is the correct way to inject a library only in a directive or at least just to load it only when I needed it
rather than loading it from the beginning?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the script dynamically - that is when your directive is executed. The most basic way to do it is using pure JS.

```
var js_script = document.createElement('script');
js_script.type = "text/javascript";
js_script.src = "http://www.example.com/script.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js_script);
```

Also you can use JQuery [getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

If you need to go pure Angular, use `$http` to get the script and [new Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) to execute it.

**Note**

Please note that you can only `inject` an angular dependency in to an angular module. What you are talking about here is loading the script needed by the directive only when it is needed. You can't call that dependency injection. It is lazy loading.

Comment: Thx for the Note...It is nice to clarify concepts :)

Answer (score -1):

To use a library, provide a src path of that library in base.html. After it, the library is going to be available throughout the application and you can use that library directly, without injecting or referencing it from anywhere

e.g.

To use lodash.js library, provide srcpath of library inside main.html.
In directive, controller and services function, use lodash directly using _(underscore) variable provided by lodash library.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a module, inject the 3rd party library module into the module and then create your custom directive in that same module, and you will be able to access the 3rd party library from your directive just by injecting the 3rd party library (provider, service, etc) directly into the directive.

Regarding the part of not loading everything at the beginning, you might be interested in [lazy loading](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad).